# Retrieve data from database in a time period between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb

I have an HTML table where I show records received in realtime from devices.

I want to allow the users to get the data from a time interval between 2 dates, for example, retrieve all the data between '2019-09-20' and '2019-09-25' at night (from 22:00:00 to 06:00:00 next day) where all the data is stored on UTC.

I am able to get it working from 06:00:00 UTC to 08:00:00 UTC retrieveing many results, but not for this query (22:12:00 UTC TO 08:00:00 UTC).

This query returns results:

```
SELECT d0_.id AS id_0
     , d0_.uuid AS uuid_1
     , d0_.datetime_utc AS datetime_utc_2
     , d0_.macaddress AS macaddress_3 
     , d0_.channel_name AS channel_name_5
     , d0_.device_id AS device_id_42
     , d0_.country_id AS country_id_43 
  FROM detection d0_ 
  JOIN device d4_ 
    ON d0_.device_id = d4_.id 
  JOIN country c7_ 
    ON d0_.country_id = c7_.id 
 WHERE (DATE(d0_.datetime_utc) BETWEEN '2019-09-20' AND '2019-09-25')
   AND (TIME(d0_.datetime_utc) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '08:00:00') 
 ORDER 
    BY d0_.datetime_utc ASC;
```

This is the result log returned on MySQL Workbench:

```
1000 row(s) returned
```

Now, if I run the query to get the results between the same date interval and between (22:00:00 UTC) to (08:00:00 UTC):

```sql
SELECT d0_.id AS id_0, d0_.uuid AS uuid_1, d0_.datetime_utc AS datetime_utc_2, d0_.macaddress AS macaddress_3, d0_.channel_name AS channel_name_5, d0_.device_id AS device_id_42, d0_.country_id AS country_id_43 
FROM detection d0_ 
INNER JOIN device d4_ ON d0_.device_id = d4_.id 
INNER JOIN country c7_ ON d0_.country_id = c7_.id 
WHERE (DATE(d0_.datetime_utc) BETWEEN '2019-09-20' AND '2019-09-25')
AND (TIME(d0_.datetime_utc) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '08:00:00') 
ORDER BY d0_.datetime_utc ASC;
```

The query returns this result (although the time interval is bigger than the first one):

```
0 row(s) returned
```

I think it is caused because the start time is bigger than the endtime, but I don't know how to resolve it.

To make clear the question, the query is described as:

```
"Give me all the records received all the days at night (defined by the TIME sentence) between 2 specific dates (defined by DATE sentence)."
```

Thanks,

Joaquín.

Answer (score 1):

Test two intervals, one from 00:00:00 to 08:00:00, and another from 22:00:00 to 23:59:59.

I'm not sure if you have time data with a resolution greater than one second. If you do, you might have to do something like 23:59:59.999.

Comment: `AND (TIME(d0_.datetime_utc) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND ' 23:59:59' OR TIME(d0_.datetime_utc) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:00:00')` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, It may work in some cases but it could cause some issues. For example, if an user with datetime == UTC + 2 filters from September 1st from 01:00:00 AM, the date stored on the database that match this condition is August 31th 23:00:00. If the user also filter by date from September 1st, this result would be excluded from the results.

Comment: I was only trying to provide was a solution for the initial given criteria. If you're dealing with shifting time zones, any solution is obviously going to be more complex. But the basic principle is the same -- break apart any time span that crosses midnight into two spans. That, and you need to be clear on which date in the date range each span is considered to "belong" to, e.g., given a span that goes from 21:00-1:00, and 21:00 is on Friday, is the next 0:30 treated as belonging to Saturday, or a pseudo-extended part of Friday?